# ¿ Como superponer un TextView en un Layout con fondo?

Tags: android-studio, xml, layout, fondo

**EDITADO:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/file_type_logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="681dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/foto_page_1" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/file_type_logo_1"
    android:layout_width="102dp"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/downarrow" />





</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `LinearLayout`, designa las posiciones de sus hijos de manera lineal según la propiedad `orientation` que definiste. Esto quiere decir que en tu caso al definir `vertical`, cada elemento que agregues a ese Layout irá uno debajo de otro. No se ve tú `TextView` en tu caso, porque al `ImageView` tener el mismo tamaño que abarca el `LinearLayout`, el `TextView` se agrega debajo y no es visible. Tú solución es utilizar un `Layout` diferente que acepte un orden Z (superposición) como por ejemplo `FrameLayout` o `RelativeLayout` si quieres crear una relación entre los elementos.

Comment: Te invito a que revises los diferentes tipos de `Layout` que existen para Android y sepas cuándo utilizar cada uno en su momento.

Comment: @Andrespengineer he editado como lo estoy haciendo pero sin exito...

Comment: Cuando utilizas `RelativeLayout` debes utilizar ciertas propiedades para ubicar los elementos de acuerdo a la relación que une el hijo con el padre, ejemplo, si aplicas la propiedad `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` hará que tu `TextView` se ubique en el fondo del `RelativeLayout`, está propiedad es propia de `RelativeLayout` quiere decir que no funcionará si utilizas esa propiedad con un `View` que no esté dentro de un `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Si solo quieres que aparezca ese `TextView` simplemente utiliza `FrameLayout` y al `TextView` asigna la propiedad `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"` con un `android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"` o  también puedes utilizar `ConstraintLayout` pero debes saber cómo se utiliza.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora que pude entender mejor lo que buscabas, creo que tengo el xml que necesitas:

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center">


   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/file_type_logo"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/foto_page_1" />


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/file_type_logo_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Hola mundo"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/downarrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Lo importante en estos cambios son: layout_alignParentBottom="true", esta propiedad la podes usar dentro de cualquier relative y sirve para indicar que esa vista puntual se alinee con la parte inferior del relative, tambien existe layout_alignParentTop, left, right, ble...
Ademas le agregue un poco de margen con marginBottom="20dp" para que no quede pegado contra fondo.

Comment: Sí, eso lo voy a editar pues no lo habia actualizado, lo que me refiero es que quiero colocar el texto en la parte superior del layout

Comment: por favor, podrias explicar mejor como quieres que se vea? o hacer un dibujito? Asi tal cual como lo puse el TextView se veria al final.

Comment: Ya está editado, miralo arriba, lo azul es el imageview y lo rojo el textview

Comment: En ese caso no lo podras resolver con un Linear Layout porque esta diseñado para poner elementos de forma lineal y no te va a dejar superponer elementos, para eso podes usar cualquier otro layout como un RelativeLayout o un CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Si, eso estoy haciendo pero sin exito

Comment: he corregido como lo estoy haciendo pero sin exito, erick

Comment: genial, ahi edito la respuesta y te agrego el relative como queda